# Returning result in array of arrays with PHP, MySQLi and prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on the following code:

```
$UID = $_POST['userID'];
$rows = [];
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
$sql = "SELECT tname, tlname, tadd, tphone FROM `users` WHERE userID =?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $UID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($tname, $tlname, $tadd, $tphone);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
echo json_encode($rows);
```

What I need is getting the result like

```
 [
    ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"],
    ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"],
    ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"],
    ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"]
 ]
```

### Update

I tried to do this by

```
 while($stmt->fetch()){
            array_push($rows, $tname, $tlname, $tadd, $tphone);
        }
```

but this is adding all values into one big array!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, since a user ID should be unique and there should always be 1 row. Also, a user ID should be submitted through a session cause this code is viable to injection.

Comment: Thanks for  hints Xorifelse, but for now I would like to know how to return the result in an array of arrays? I know logically this is not a good sample but lets assume that each users has many record in  this specific table!

Answer (score 0):

[`mysqli_stmt::execute()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) is used for `insert`, `update` and `delete` statements. Rather than returning a result set it returns the number of rows effected by the statement. When performing a `select` you need to use [`mysqli_stmt::get_result()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) which will return a [`mysqli_result`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) instance. You can then call [`fetch_all()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) on the `mysqli_result` to retrieve all rows of the result set as an array of associative arrays.